# How to compile .g4 to .cs?

Tags: c#, antlr4cs

I reread all documentations but still didn't get what exactly do I need to do. **Please explain step by step what do I need to do to set up work with Antlr in VS2019 (for C#) and how can I compile .g4 to .cs after.** Do I need to install Antlr4 or Antlr4.Runtime or Antlr4.Runtime.Standard? Do I need to download "antlr-4.8-complete.jar" file from official site? If so, what should I do with it after? In general, as you can see, I'm confused in it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to use ANTLR in combination with C#, though I can tell you that Antlr4 is used to generate the code, and that the Runtime libraries are required by the generated code. So to the generate the code I think you need the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this way--not because I wrote the software--but because it is easy and uses the most up-to-date release of Antlr:

- Install the NET SDK (aka "dotnet.exe").
- dotnet new -i Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates
- dotnet new antlr
- dotnet build
- dotnet run

You can then open VS2019 or VSCode on the .csproj. See [Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks/tree/master/Templates). It uses [Antlr4BuildTask](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks) for building. You don't need to install Java nor Antlr--it includes a copy of the Java JRE and Antlr. But, you will need connectivity to NuGet.org.

If for whatever reason you need to generate the .cs files outside of a build, then you can type it in from a shell:

- java -jar ~/Downloads/antlr-4.8-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp *.g4

Note, [Antlr4.Runtime.Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime.Standard/) is the current Antlr runtime for C# as a `netstandard1.3;net35` package. [Antlr4.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime/) is Harwell's port of the entire Antlr Java code and runtime v4.6.6 to C#, and, as far as I know, it is not being maintained. There is a tool in that package that is the equivalent to the Java-based Antlr tool, so you can use that in a similar way. But, it is roughly 3 years behind the current release v4.8--soon to be [v4.9](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2932). The Antlr4BuildTasks package I wrote is a modification of Harwell's package, but instead calls the Java-based Antlr tool.

Support within an editor for Antlr in VS2019, VSCode, or what have you, for syntactic or semantic highlighting, goto refs, goto def, etc., should be considered separate from the build of your app. [Harwell's extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.ANTLRLanguageSupport) is for VS2017. For VSCode, you have the choice of Mike's [vscode-antlr](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4) or my LSP-based tool [Antlrvsix-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KenDomino.Antlrvsix-vscode). For VS2019, you can use my extension [Antlrvsix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KenDomino.AntlrVSIX), or one of the few unsupported and very old extensions. Or, you can skip all that, and just edit it as text.

Comment: I will advise to insert the generated code in a DLL project then reference this DLL in your project. This way you don't have to compile it each time you run your project.